# How to customize the Intent chooser when share file across Profile?

Tags: android

My android phone is [work profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en) enabled. When I share a file from app (such as an image), a chooser dialog (1st dialog) appear with new feature added:

[image]

Touch this icon will show it's choose dialog (2nd dialog):
[image]

Is there any way to customize the second dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default system behavior, I believe there is no way to change this.

But there are some articles that will help you achieve this by implementing deeplink and BottomSheet. Try [this](http://www.hidroh.com/2016/06/17/bottom-sheet-everything/)